# UIWebView cache not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to cache my UIWebView for when I have no network connection but it doesn't work. I tried looking into HanekeSwift but that only works with JSON requests as far as I could find.

This is what I currently have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let id = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("id") as! String

    let url = NSURL (string: "http://****.php?id=\(id)");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    subtitleLabel.loadRequest(requestObj);
}
```

Comment: Create `requestObj` with specific cache policy `ReturnCacheDataDontLoad` if you can tell there is no network, or use the default behavior.

Comment: It somehow gives me this error `0x196a994c8 <+28>:  ldr    x9, [x19] WebThread (6): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1, address=0x8)`

Comment: There are webview on my app where this DOES work but on some of them it somehow gives that error while they are exactly the same..

Comment: I noticed it works only when I use the code I have currently first > view the page > change the code to ReturnCacheDontLoad > Rebuild > view the page. Otherwise it gives me the error. So weird.

Answer (score 0):

My question was answered here:
[Getting error with cachePolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606196/getting-error-with-cachepolicy#32606351)

Thanks to KudoCC for pointing me in the right direction I got this as my final code:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "****.php?page=over_polen")
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 5);
webViewLabel.loadRequest(requestObj);
```

Comment: If there is network, you should always use `UseProtocolCachePolicy`, because `ReturnCacheDataElseLoad` would load the local cache even the source file on the server has been updated.

Comment: I just bumped in to this problem thanks! I will search on how to find internet connection availability for this