# Getting error with cachePolicy

Tags: ios, swift

Since I am using `cachePolicy` in my UIWebView I get this error:

`0x196a994c8 <+28>: ldr x9, [x19] WebThread (6): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1, address=0x8)`

If I open the view without the cachePolicy in the code first, afterwards edit the code to have the cachePolicy and build it again, it does work.

But if I launch the view directly with cachePolicy on a phone that never launched that view before it doesn't work.

This is my code (giving the error):

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://visia-ontwikkeling.nl/polen/pages.php?page=information_point")
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataDontLoad, timeoutInterval: 5);
webViewLabel.loadRequest(requestObj);
```

And this is how it does work, but no cache:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://visia-ontwikkeling.nl/polen/pages.php?page=information_point")
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
webViewLabel.loadRequest(requestObj);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to check [NSUrlCache](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/). Your cache policy is wrong i think. You force your request to get cached data even if it is not exist. You should use `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad`. Such as:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://visia-ontwikkeling.nl/polen/pages.php?page=information_point")
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy. ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 5)
webViewLabel.loadRequest(requestObj)
```